# Does JavaME and/or Proguard reorder assignments?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me, proguard, synchronized

This is a simplified example - I have two threads:

Can JavaME and/Proguard ever reorder the `obX = ...` statements, such that thread_B will have a null pointer exception at `ob1.someMethod`?

thread_A:

```
Object ob1 = null;
Object ob2 = null;
...
ob1 = something1;
ob2 = something2;
```

thread_B:

```
if (ob2 != null) {
    ob1.someMethod();
    ...
}
```

P.S. I do realise that synchronising these will avoid the issue.  Synchronisation has both a performance overhead, and more importantly, a chance to introduce deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current versions of ProGuard (up to version 4.8 at this time of writing) don't reorder such statements. However, the Java memory model does allow the reordering if the fields are not volatile, so you shouldn't rely on it. The Java virtual machine, future versions of ProGuard, or other tools may very well reorder the code. At least volatile fields won't introduce deadlocks.

Comment: "Java ME platforms are currently restricted to JRE 1.3" ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_ME)) => formally this means JMM (JSR 166) doesn't apply. Although your reasoning per se remains applicable: JMM just stated explicitly and officially what was there for all prior versions, that non-volatile / non-sync'd assignments can be reordered

Comment: Thanks, I've marked the two variables in question `volatile`.  I've never seen this problem occur, but this in embedded code so it is rather critical.